# Appending items to appended items with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, append

I am new to JavaScript and jquery and am trying to append an ordered list of items to create a ui in a web app.

The problem that I am facing is trying to append an item if it has the same product code as an all ready appended item to the details div that should hold all the items with the same product code as in the code below.

In the code I first check to see if the pai number is the same as the previous one as each pai number can have multiple item numbers like 123445 - 1 , 12345 - 2, 12345 - 3 etc.

I then check to see if the product code is the same or not in the next if statement as each pai could have multiple items with different product codes and if its not different append it to the first item at the second details div.

If the product code is the same it should be appended to the details div that holds the same product code.

The structure should look something like this.

```
<li>
  <details>
   <details>
     product code1
     product code1
   <details>
   <details>
     product code2
     product code2
     product code2
     product code2 
   <details>
   <details>
     product code3
     product code3
  <details>
<details>
</li>
```

But ends up being more like this

```
<li>
  <details>
   <details>
     product code1
   <details>
   <details>
     product code2
   <details>
   <details>
     product code3
  <details>
  product code1
  product code1
  product code2
  product code2
  product code3
<details>
</li>
```

I cant attach any images otherwise I would take a screen shot of the div structure to help explain more.

```
    var elementApended;
    var lastpai;
    var itemList = new Object();

        query.read().then(function(todoItems) {
            var listItems = $.map(todoItems, function (item) {
                if (item.painumber !== lastpai) {
                    for (var member in itemList) delete itemList[member];
                    elementApended = $('<details class="middle-div"></details>')
                    .append($('<details class="middle-div"></details>')
                    .append($('<div class="middle-middle-div"></div>')
                    .attr('data-todoitem-id', item.id)
                    .attr('data-todoitem-pai', item.painumber)
                    .attr('data-todoitem-item', item.itemnumber)
                    .attr('data-todoitem-link', item.drawingurl)
                    .append($('<div class="item-div"></div>').append($('<div class="Pai-Head"></div>').append(item.painumber))
                    .append($('<div class="Item-Head"></div>').append(item.itemnumber))
                    .append($('<div class="Product-Head"></div>').append(item.productcode))
                    .append($('<div class="Size-Head"></div>').append(item.xsize + " X " + item.ysize))
                    .append($('<div class="Qty-Head"></div>').append(item.quantity))
                    .append($('<div class="Disp-Head"></div>').append(item.dispatchdatetoshow)))
                    .append($('<div class="Button-Head"></div>').append('<button class="new-ncr-button">Raise New NCR</button>').append('<button class="new-di-button">New Drawing Issue</button>').append('<button class="view-drawings-button">View Product Drawings</button>'))
                    .append($('<details class="mods-div"><summary class="mods-summary">Check The Modifications Here</summary></details>').append($('<div class="mods-text">').append(item.modifications))))).appendTo('<li>');
                    lastpai = item.painumber;
                    itemList[item.productcode] = elementApended;
                    return elementApended;
                } else {
                    if (itemList.hasOwnProperty(item.productcode)) {
                        return $(itemList[item.productcode])
                        .append($('<div class="middle-middle-div"></div>')
                        .attr('data-todoitem-id', item.id)
                        .attr('data-todoitem-pai', item.painumber)
                        .attr('data-todoitem-item', item.itemnumber)
                        .attr('data-todoitem-link', item.drawingurl)
                        .append($('<div class="item-div"></div>').append($('<div class="Pai-Head"></div>').append(item.painumber))
                        .append($('<div class="Item-Head"></div>').append(item.itemnumber))
                        .append($('<div class="Product-Head"></div>').append(item.productcode))
                        .append($('<div class="Size-Head"></div>').append(item.xsize + " X " + item.ysize))
                        .append($('<div class="Qty-Head"></div>').append(item.quantity))
                        .append($('<div class="Disp-Head"></div>').append(item.dispatchdatetoshow)))
                        .append($('<div class="Button-Head"></div>').append('<button class="new-ncr-button">Raise New NCR</button>').append('<button class="new-di-button">New Drawing Issue</button>').append('<button class="view-drawings-button">View Product Drawings</button>'))
                        .append($('<details class="mods-div"><summary class="mods-summary">Check The Modifications Here</summary></details>').append($('<div class="mods-text">').append(item.modifications))));
                    } else {
                        secondElementApended = $(elementApended)
                        .append($('<details class="middle-div"></details>')
                        .append($('<div class="middle-middle-div"></div>')
                        .attr('data-todoitem-id', item.id)
                        .attr('data-todoitem-pai', item.painumber)
                        .attr('data-todoitem-item', item.itemnumber)
                        .attr('data-todoitem-link', item.drawingurl)
                        .append($('<div class="item-div"></div>').append($('<div class="Pai-Head"></div>').append(item.painumber))
                        .append($('<div class="Item-Head"></div>').append(item.itemnumber))
                        .append($('<div class="Product-Head"></div>').append(item.productcode))
                        .append($('<div class="Size-Head"></div>').append(item.xsize + " X " + item.ysize))
                        .append($('<div class="Qty-Head"></div>').append(item.quantity))
                        .append($('<div class="Disp-Head"></div>').append(item.dispatchdatetoshow)))
                        .append($('<div class="Button-Head"></div>').append('<button class="new-ncr-button">Raise New NCR</button>').append('<button class="new-di-button">New Drawing Issue</button>').append('<button class="view-drawings-button">View Product Drawings</button>'))
                        .append($('<details class="mods-div"><summary class="mods-summary">Check The Modifications Here</summary></details>').append($('<div class="mods-text">').append(item.modifications)))));
                        itemList[item.productcode] = secondElementApended;
                        return secondElementApended;
                    }
                }
        });
```

If any one could guide me in the right direction or give me some tips on looking at a better way of doing this they would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you try to re-write your first paragraph to be more descriptive, I'm sure one of us can help but not quite sure what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Just by looking at your code I cannot see what's the need of all those append and attr since it can be easily done using `$("<tag />", {attr1:val1, attr2:val2, html: element, ...})`

Comment: You can create helper function that returns a desired element, or a nested HTML string concatenated with variables. More readable than that in any case...

Comment: Also inside the `if / else` you repeat-your-self. When you see such bunch of seamless code that differ by just a couple of returns... time to rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this one out for myself in the end I will post the code in case any one else comes across this issue.

I think trying to do the appends in the map was causing the issue.

```
    function refreshTodoItems(filter) {

    var elementToApended;
    var lastPai;
    var itemList = new Object();
    var listItems;

    $('#todo-items').empty();

    if (filter) {
        var query = todoItemTable.where({ painumber: filter, producttype: 'manufactured' })
        .orderBy('dispatchdate')
        .orderBy('painumber')
        .orderBy('itemnumber')
        .take(500);
    } else {
        var query = todoItemTable.where({ producttype: 'manufactured' })
        .orderBy('dispatchdate')
        .orderBy('painumber')
        .orderBy('itemnumber')
        .take(500);
    }

    query.read().done(function (todoItems) {

        for (i = 0; i < todoItems.length; i++) {
            if (todoItems[i].painumber !== lastPai) {
                createGuiItems(todoItems[i]);
            }
            lastPai = todoItems[i].painumber;
        }

    }, handleError );

    function createGuiItems(item) {

        var query2 = todoItemTable.where({ painumber: item.painumber, producttype: 'manufactured' })
            .orderBy('dispatchdate')
            .orderBy('painumber')
            .orderBy('itemnumber');

        query2.read().done(function (item) {

            for (var member in itemList) delete itemList[member];

            elementToApended = $('<details class="middle-div" id="' + item[0].painumber + '"></details>').appendTo('<li>');

            for (i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {

                    if ((itemList.hasOwnProperty(item[i].productcode)) && (item[i].itemnumber !== 1)) {
                        var thirdElementApended = $('<div class="middle-middle-div"></div>', { 'data-todoitem-id': item[i].id, 'data-todoitem-item': item[i].painumber, 'data-todoitem-item': item[i].itemnumber, 'data-todoitem-link': item[i].drawingurl })
                        .append($('<div class="item-div"></div>').append($('<div class="Pai-Head"></div>').append(item[i].painumber))
                        .append($('<div class="Item-Head"></div>').append(item[i].itemnumber))
                        .append($('<div class="Product-Head"></div>').append(item[i].productcode))
                        .append($('<div class="Size-Head"></div>').append(item[i].xsize + " X " + item[i].ysize))
                        .append($('<div class="Qty-Head"></div>').append(item[i].quantity))
                        .append($('<div class="Disp-Head"></div>').append(item[i].dispatchdatetoshow)))
                        .append($('<div class="Button-Head"></div>').append('<button class="new-ncr-button">Raise New NCR</button>').append('<button class="new-di-button">New Drawing Issue</button>').append('<button class="view-drawings-button">View Product Drawings</button>'))
                        .append($('<details class="mods-div"><summary class="mods-summary">Check The Modifications Here</summary></details>').append($('<div class="mods-text">').append(item[i].modifications)));
                        $(elementToApended).find('#' + item[i].productcode).append(thirdElementApended)
                    } else {
                        var secondElementApended = $('<details class="middle-div" id="' + item[i].productcode + '"></details>')
                        .append($('<div class="middle-middle-div"></div>', { 'data-todoitem-id': item[i].id, 'data-todoitem-item': item[i].painumber, 'data-todoitem-item': item[i].itemnumber, 'data-todoitem-link': item[i].drawingurl })
                        .append($('<div class="item-div"></div>').append($('<div class="Pai-Head"></div>').append(item[i].painumber))
                        .append($('<div class="Item-Head"></div>').append(item[i].itemnumber))
                        .append($('<div class="Product-Head"></div>').append(item[i].productcode))
                        .append($('<div class="Size-Head"></div>').append(item[i].xsize + " X " + item[i].ysize))
                        .append($('<div class="Qty-Head"></div>').append(item[i].quantity))
                        .append($('<div class="Disp-Head"></div>').append(item[i].dispatchdatetoshow)))
                        .append($('<div class="Button-Head"></div>').append('<button class="new-ncr-button">Raise New NCR</button>').append('<button class="new-di-button">New Drawing Issue</button>').append('<button class="view-drawings-button">View Product Drawings</button>'))
                        .append($('<details class="mods-div"><summary class="mods-summary">Check The Modifications Here</summary></details>').append($('<div class="mods-text">').append(item[i].modifications))));
                        $(elementToApended).append(secondElementApended)
                        itemList[item[i].productcode] = 1;
                    }

                }

            $('#todo-items').append(elementToApended)

            $('.mods-text:empty').each(function () {
                if (jQuery.trim($(this).val()) == "") $(this).parent().remove();
            });

            $('.Product-Head').each(function () {
                var val = $(this).text();
                if ((val.indexOf('B1000') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('B2000') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('B3000') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('B4000') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('B5000') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('B6000') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('B7000') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('B8000') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('B9000') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('B-') !== -1)) {
                    $(this).parent().parent().css('border-color', 'red');
                }

                if ((val.indexOf('SK1000') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('SK2000') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('SK3000') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('SK4000') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('SK5000') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('SK6000') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('SK7000') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('SK8000') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('SK9000') !== -1)) {
                    $(this).parent().parent().css('border-color', 'green');
                }

                if ((val.indexOf('TL') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('Plastic') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('Plastics') !== -1)) {
                    $(this).parent().parent().css('border-color', 'green');
                }

                if ((val.indexOf('N1000') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('N2000') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('N3000') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('N4000') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('N5000') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('N6000') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('N7000') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('N8000') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('N9000') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('NFC') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('NSC') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('NPS') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('N-') !== -1)) {
                    $(this).parent().parent().css('border-color', 'blue');
                }

                if ((val.indexOf('S1000') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('S2000') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('S3000') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('S4000') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('S5000') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('S6000') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('S7000') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('S8000') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('S9000') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('SFC') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('SSC') !== -1) || (val.indexOf('SPS') !== -1)) {
                    $(this).parent().parent().css('border-color', 'blue');
                }

                $('#summary').html('<strong>' + $('#todo-items > details').length + '</strong> Order(s) Incomplete');
                $('#errorlog').empty();

            });

        }, handleError );
    }

}
```